# Twitter share with back button using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm not much experienced in Rails. I'm trying to implement Twitter sharing in my project.

```
<li class="twitter">
                    <a onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/share?text=<%= tweet_text %>&amp;url=','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" class="popup" href="javascript: void(0)"></a>
                </li>
```

and this will open up a tweet page in a new window in case of browsers. But in case of iPad or iPhone this thing loads in the same tab and the user will be stuck at that page if he or she thinks not to tweet when it loads.

So what I want is that I need a tweet page that comes with a back button or cancel button or something similar to that which can solve this.

Comment: Take a look at this approach => http://gpiot.s1.cotidia.com/twitter-share-demo/. In case the user doesn't want to share anymore they can simply go back from iOs navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post has been here for one year but I am answering it anyway. I believe you are looking for this

```
 <a onclick="window.open('http://twitter.com/share?text=<%= @post.title %> by @yourname- &amp;url=<%= url_for([@post,{only_path: false}])%>','_blank','width=800,height=500,top=200,left=300');void(0);" >
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
```